# Expression in Polars select context that refers to earlier alias

Tags: python-polars

Is there a way to allow an expression in Polars to refer to a previous aliased expression? For example, this code that defines two new columns errors because the second new column refers to the first:

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(dict(x=[0, 0, 1]))

df.select([
  (pl.col('x') + 1).alias('y'),
  (pl.col('y') * 2).alias('z')],
)
# pyo3_runtime.PanicException: called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value:
# NotFound("Unable to get field named \"y\". Valid fields: [\"x\"]")
```

The error makes it obvious that the failure is caused by the first alias not being visible to the second expression. Is there a straightforward way to make this work?

Answer (score 6):

All polars expressions within a **context** are executed in parallel. So they cannot refer to a column that does not yet exist.

A context is:

- `df.with_columns`
- `df.select`
- `df.groupby(..).agg`

This means you need to enforce sequential execution for expressions that reference to other expression outputs.

In your case I would do:

```py
(df.with_column(
       (pl.col('x') + 1).alias('y')
    ).select([
       pl.col('y'),
      (pl.col('y') * 2).alias('z')
]))
```

Comment: If two expressions that could be run in parallel are split into sequential contexts, does `lazy` do any optimization to recognize that, or is that not one of the things it recognizes?

Comment: @drhagen sometimes. Check out describe_optimized_plan before collecting

Answer (score 1):

One workaround is to pull out each new column into its own `with_column` call and then do a final `select` to keep the columns you were supposed to keep. You will probably want to make sure this is done lazily.

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(dict(x=[0, 0, 1]))

(df
  .lazy()
  .with_column((pl.col("x") + 1).alias("y"))
  .with_column((pl.col("y") * 2).alias("z"))
  .select(["y", "z"])
  .collect()
)
# shape: (3, 2)
# ┌─────┬─────┐
# │ y   ┆ z   │
# │ --- ┆ --- │
# │ i64 ┆ i64 │
# ╞═════╪═════╡
# │ 1   ┆ 2   │
# ├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
# │ 1   ┆ 2   │
# ├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
# │ 2   ┆ 4   │
# └─────┴─────┘
```