# Expression in Polars groupby context that refers to earlier alias

Tags: python-polars

Is there a way for an expression in an aggregation context to refer to a previous expression in the aggregation?

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(dict(
  x=[0, 0, 1, 1],
  y=[1, 2, 3, 4],
))

df.groupby("x").agg([
  pl.col("x").sum().alias("sum_x"),
  (pl.col("sum_x") / pl.count()).alias("mean_x"),
])
# pyo3_runtime.PanicException: called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value:
# NotFound("Unable to get field named \"sum_x\". Valid fields: [\"x\", \"y\"]")
```

This does not work naively because, as the error clearly indicates, expressions in a context cannot refer to previous expressions. The [workaround for the select context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71105136/expression-in-polars-that-refers-to-previous-alias) does not work for the groupby context because `agg` does not keep all the data around like `with_column` does.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the `selection` context, in the `groupby` context expressions are executed in parallel and thus cannot refer to each other in the same context.

You need to enforce sequential execution by adding a `select`:

```py
df.groupby("x").agg([
  pl.col("x").sum().alias("sum_x"),
  pl.count()
]).select([
    "sum_x",
    (pl.col("sum_x") / pl.col("count")).alias("mean_x")
])
```

Comment: Is there a solution that does not require disassembling the expressions into their scalar atoms? My expressions are coming externally, like `.agg([expression1.alias(name1), expression2.alias(name2)])`.

Comment: Or you write expressions that don't reference columns that don't exists before you start the context and you ensure a second sequential step.

Or you pay the compute price and compute twice:

`(pl.col("x").sum() / pl.count()).alias("mean_x"))` and `pl.col("x").sum() .alias("sum_x")`

Comment: We could explore a `sequential` aggreagation context. Though I think it will almost always be slower than breaking them down.