# Alias a column and continue using it in the same expression?

Tags: python-polars

In the below code, I alias two columns, `ends_in_starts` and `starts_in_ends` and continue using them. However, these columns are not part of the result. There is nothing [in the docs](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.alias.html) that indicate alias must come at the very end.

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "chromosome": ["chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr2", "chr2"],
        "starts": [0, 8, 6, 5, 0, 10],
        "ends": [6, 9, 10, 7, 11, 20],
        "genes": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "A", "B"]
    }
).sort("starts", "ends")

def search(
        col1: str,
        col2: str,
        side: str = "left"
) -> pl.Expr:
    return pl.col(col1).explode().search_sorted(pl.col(col2).explode(), side=side)

res = df.lazy().groupby("chromosome").agg(
    [
        search("starts", "ends").alias("ends_in_starts").gt(search("ends", "starts").alias("starts_in_ends")).alias("mask"),
    ]
)
```

I can do the following:

```
res = df.lazy().groupby("chromosome").agg(
    [
        search("starts", "ends").gt(search("ends", "starts")).alias("mask"),
        search("starts", "ends").alias("ends_in_starts"),
        search("ends", "starts").alias("starts_in_ends"),
    ]
)
```

But it seems like the query optimizer is unable to tell that the two last agg operations is contained in the first one.

Comment: Note that this question differs from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71105136/expression-in-polars-select-context-that-refers-to-earlier-alias since I do not ask about reusing a column created in the same context.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, the alias calls are just giving names, so the first example is equivalent to: `mask = ends_in_starts.gt(starts_in_ends)` - you're only returning a single column. Are you expecting both examples to return 3 columns?

Comment: I was hoping it was possible to return three columns in that way.

Especially since it seems that the engine does not recognize the common operations (I think, I'm not that good at reading the graph output yet).

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Why not step back from alias and articulate what you are ultimately trying to get at?

Comment: I'd like to try to optimize the operation so that I do not need to run `search("starts", "ends").alias("ends_in_starts")` twice :)