# Declare intermediate variables in select statements in Polars

Tags: python-polars

When writing `select` or `with_columns` statements in Polars I often wish to declare intermediate variables to make the code more readable. I'd also like to be able to query a column in a context and reuse it in another column's expression. I am currently forced to chain multiple `select`/`with_columns` calls which lacks elegance. Here is a fictive example of what I would like to do:

```
df.with_columns(
    [
       <some expression>.alias('step_1'), # here I want step_1 to become a column in the output table
       temporary_variable = <some other expression>, # here I want this variable not to be present in the output table
       pl.col(['step_1']).some_function(temporary_variable).alias('step_2'), # this column's expression uses both the first column: 'step_1' and temporary_variable
       pl.col(...).some_other_function(temporary_variable).alias('another_column') # temporary_variable might need to be used in multiple column's expression, being able to declare the temporary variable and reuse it makes the code shorter, more modular and avoids copy pasts
    ]
)
```

My question is: is there any way to do this in Polars?

Comment: It could be that you are just meant to declare external functions rather than declaring temporary variables... If someone could confirm this that would be great.

Comment: For `step_1` it sounds like you're asking: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71108312 - https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/9062#issuecomment-1610906158 - As for temporary variable, expressions are "lazy", so you can create them outside and put them into variables e.g. `my_temp_expr = pl.col(...).something(); df.with_columns(my_temp_expr, ..., ...)`

Comment: @jqurious check out my answer for a walrus trick.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor Very interesting approach. Never used `:=` before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can actually use [walrus assignment](https://realpython.com/python-walrus-operator/) to get very close to what you're after

Say you have this:

```
df = pl.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[2,3,4], 'c':[3,4,5]})
```

You can do:

```
df.with_columns(
    (step_1 := (pl.col('a') * 2)).alias('step_1'),
    step_1.pow(tempvar := ((pl.col('b') + 1.5))).alias('step_2'),
    (pl.col('c') + tempvar).alias('another_column')
    )
```

The catch is that now we have a `step_1` and `tempvar` variable in our global environment.

From a readability perspective you have to type `step_1` twice on the first line which, I believe, is unavoidable. Your `tempvar` assignment can't happen until the first time you go to use it rather than before. You can, of course, insert line breaks so that you still see it on its own line if you want.

[For performance concerns, also remember:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71108312/1818713):

> All polars expressions within a context are executed in parallel. So they cannot refer to a column that does not yet exist.

What the walrus assignment is picking up isn't a final answer but an expression. That means the above is computationally equivalent to:

```
df.with_columns(
    (pl.col('a') * 2).alias('step_1'),
    (pl.col('a') * 2).pow((pl.col('b') + 1.5)).alias('step_2'),
    (pl.col('c') + (pl.col('b') + 1.5)).alias('another_column')
    )
```

If your `step_1` and `tempvar` are cheap then the readability tradeoff is probably good even though there will be redundant calculations. If they aren't cheap then you can try to use [`cache`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.cache.html#polars.Expr.cache) to only compute it once but the docs have this warning:

> This can actually hurt performance and can have a lot of contention. It is advised not to use it until actually benchmarked on your problem.

On a slight tangent, in terms of readability, you can also use dictionary unpacking to get rid of using alias like this:

```
df.with_columns(**{
    'step_1': (step_1 := (pl.col('a') * 2)),
    'step_2': step_1.pow(tempvar := ((pl.col('b') + 1.5))),
    'another_column': (pl.col('c') + tempvar)
    })
```

That's just a matter of preference though.