How to chain multiple with_columns in Polars?
I'm using Polars to transform my DataFrame, and I want to chain multiple with_columns transformations. However, I encounter an issue when trying to perform operations on a newly created column within the same with_columns context. I end up needing to save the DataFrame after each transformation and then reapply with_columns for subsequent transformations.
Is there a cleaner way to achieve this?
Here is an example of my current approach:
import polars as pl

# Sample data
exampledata = {
    'A': [1, 2, 3],
    'B': [4, 5, 6]
}

df = pl.DataFrame(exampledata)

# First transformation
df = df.with_columns(
    (pl.col("A") + pl.col("B")).alias("C")
)

# Second transformation
df = df.with_columns(
    (pl.col("C") * pl.col("B")).alias("D")
)

print(df)

In this example, I create a new column C from columns A and B. Then, I need to save the DataFrame before I can create column D from C and B. Is there a more efficient or idiomatic way to chain these transformations in Polars?

in question (not in comments) you should show how you chain it, and what issue you get.

do you mean executing with many values df.with_columns(X, Y) or chaining df.with_columns(X).with_columns(Y)

Hi!  @furas I'm trying to perform multiple column transformations using with_columns in Polars. However, if I want to use a newly created column in a subsequent operation, I need to assign the DataFrame and then use the new column. Is there a more efficient way to chain these transformations?

for me "chaning" means df.with_columns(X).with_columns(Y) and it works correctly.

For performance reasons, all expressions in a single pl.DataFrame.with_columns context are evaluated in parallel. Especially, it is not possible to use a column resulting from an expression in a different expression in the same context.1
1 This does not mean that polars performs duplicate work for expressions with common sub-expressions since under the hood a Common-Subplan-Elimination mechanism is used.

Still, since with_columns returns the resulting dataframe, you do not need to assign each result back to df, but can chain the with_columns calls directly as follows.
df = (
    df
    .with_columns(
        (pl.col("A") + pl.col("B")).alias("C")
    )
    .with_columns(
        (pl.col("C") * pl.col("B")).alias("D")
    )
)

shape: (3, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ A   ┆ B   ┆ C   ┆ D   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 4   ┆ 5   ┆ 20  │
│ 2   ┆ 5   ┆ 7   ┆ 35  │
│ 3   ┆ 6   ┆ 9   ┆ 54  │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘


You can use the walrus operator to syntactically have intermediate results in the same with_columns. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76668373/declare-intermediate-variables-in-select-statements-in-polars/76687175#76687175

@DeanMacGregor Personally, I'd prefer to declare c_expr = pl.col("A") + pl.col("B") and, then, use it twice in a single .with_columns context, but interesting approach nevertheless. Thanks :)

I meant it more for OP. Guess I should have flagged @Simon to begin with.

The existing answer is correct in that Polars will likely optimise the multiple with_columns calls if you are in lazy mode (operating on a LazyFrame). If you are not, then it will not be optimised.
Another alternative is to store the initial computation in a variable.
a_plus_b = pl.col("A") + pl.col("B")

df.with_columns(
    a_plus_b.alias("C"),
    (a_plus_b * pl.col("B")).alias("D")
)

shape: (3, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ A   ┆ B   ┆ C   ┆ D   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 4   ┆ 5   ┆ 20  │
│ 2   ┆ 5   ┆ 7   ┆ 35  │
│ 3   ┆ 6   ┆ 9   ┆ 54  │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘

An additional alternative, as pointed out in the comments is to use the walrus operator to do this assignment from within the with_columns as seen here.
